# Accidentaly shorted Arduino Leonardo VIN pin to GROUND. Is my board fried for ever?

Tags: arduino, ground, short-circuit

I accidentaly shorted the Vin pin to the Leonardo's GND pin and the ON led flashed. After the flash, the L led turned on with the ON led and stayed that way. Then the AtMega32u4 started to heat up fairly quickly, so of course I unplugged it. My power source at the time was DC 9.6V 600mA.
I tried pressing the reset button countless times and it doesnt do anything, and I've also tried uploading new, empty code, but the Leonardo doesnt even open the port. I guess since the AtMega is heating up, it is because something somewhere is fried. but, is that something replaceable?

Comment: Sounds like the regulator is toast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep sounds like it's fried. If you are new to electronics replacing the AtMega might be difficult as it is an SMD soldered part. You would also need to load the Arduino boot loader on a new chip and that is something that requires a programmer.

I would suggest just getting a new Arduino and coming back to fix this one once you feel comfortable to troubleshoot the problem. That is a cheaper option compared to buying a programmer and parts you may need to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the resistance between the VIN and GND of the Arduino. Generally the resistance is above `20M`.

If accidently you have shorted it then it will fall in the range of `kilo ohms` which means that any other short circuit will damage it permanently.